# Create Association Through Two Different Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

User:

```
User
has_and_belongs_to_many :user_jobs, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Job"
has_many :jobs, through: :locations
has_many :customers, through: :locations
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
```

Location:

```
Location
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
has_many :jobs
```

Customer:

```
Customer
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
```

Job:

```
Job
belongs_to :customer
belongs_to :location
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Here is my Schema.rb file

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more 
migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180308214356) do

  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "company_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "stripe_publishable_key"
    t.text "stripe_account_id"
    t.text "twilio_account_sid"
    t.text "twilio_auth_token"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "location_id"
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_categories_on_location_id"
  end

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "middle_initial"
    t.string "last_name"

    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "account_id"
    t.text "stripe_customer_id"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_customers_on_account_id"
  end

  create_table "customers_locations", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "location_id", null: false
    t.integer "customer_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "drafts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone_one"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end



  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "time"
    t.boolean "time_sensitive"
    t.text "address_line_one"
    t.text "address_line_two"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.text "special_instructions"
    t.text "description"
    t.text "work_completed"
    t.text "billing_information"
    t.text "notes"
    t.string "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_customer_id"
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_location_id"
  end

  create_table "jobs_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "job_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "account_id"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_locations_on_account_id"
  end



  create_table "locations_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "location_id", null: false
  end


  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "location_id"
    t.integer "account_id"
    t.integer "role_id"

    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_users_on_location_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_users_on_role_id"
  end

end
```

With this model structure I can query the jobs model in two different ways. First user.user_jobs and  `user.jobs`. Both of these queries return two different result sets. I need to be able to do the same thing with the customers. I can currently query `user.customers` but I do not know what syntax I should use to make user.user_customers work so that the query joins with the users' related jobs and then grabs the customers related to those jobs. My current query joins the users' locations and grabs the customers associated with those locations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  has_many :user_job_customers, through: :user_jobs, source: 'customers'
  has_many :location_customers, through: :locations, source: 'customers'
```

I guess you need :source option

Comment: I've updated my question please review if you don't mind.

Comment: Could you add all your models and your schema?